# Using SQL Over Statement with rolling sum

Tags: sql-server, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I am trying to keep track of a rolling sum that is calculated using the prior year worth of data.

Currently I have this as my SQL:

```
SELECT lngTIMEID as Id,
        lngEMPID as EmployeeId,
        dtmdateapp AS [Date], 
        stroccur AS [Value],
        (SELECT Sum(stroccur) 
         FROM   [Attendance].[dbo].timeuse a 
         WHERE  a.dtmdateapp between DateAdd(d, -366, d.dtmdateapp) 
                AND d.dtmDATEAPP
                AND a.lngempid = d.lngempid) AS Total
 FROM   [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] d
         WHERE lngEMPID =  1844140 AND absence = 'Unscheduled' AND lngRID IN (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
```

Which brings back a result like this:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
|   Id   | EmployeeId |   Date    | Value | Total |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| 330435 |    1844140 | 4/17/2017 |  0.25 |  0.25 |
| 330849 |    1844140 | 4/19/2017 |  0.25 |   0.5 |
| 331108 |    1844140 | 4/20/2017 |  0.25 |  0.75 |
| 331641 |    1844140 | 4/24/2017 |  0.25 |     1 |
| 331736 |    1844140 | 4/25/2017 |  0.25 |  1.25 |
| 333761 |    1844140 | 5/5/2017  |  0.25 |   1.5 |
| 336080 |    1844140 | 5/17/2017 |     1 |   2.5 |
| 349752 |    1844140 | 8/2/2017  |  0.25 |     3 | <--- this should be 2.75
| 350994 |    1844140 | 8/9/2017  |     1 |     4 |
| 351426 |    1844140 | 8/11/2017 |  0.25 |  4.25 |
| 352132 |    1844140 | 8/15/2017 |   0.5 |  4.75 |
| 354236 |    1844140 | 8/25/2017 |  0.25 |     5 |
| 355580 |    1844140 | 8/29/2017 |  0.25 |  5.25 |
| 355650 |    1844140 | 9/5/2017  |  0.25 |   5.5 |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

The idea is that it will loop through all of the occurrences and sum up the all of the prior occurrences that happen within one year of the current date.

With my current code there is an issue with the calculation where the total hits 3.

I would like to use the SQL Over statement because it calculates correctly but I am not sure how to use it with the rolling 1 year timeframe. This is what I used:

```
SELECT lngTIMEID as Id,
        lngEMPID as EmployeeId,
        dtmdateapp AS [Date], 
        stroccur AS [Value],
        sum(strOCCUR) OVER(ORDER BY dtmdateapp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as [Total]
 FROM   [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] d
         WHERE lngEMPID =  1844140 AND absence = 'Unscheduled' AND lngRID IN (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
```

and gives me the correct result because this data all occur in the same year but it wont work for the rolling 1 year time frame:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
|   Id   | EmployeeId |   Date    | Value | Total |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
| 330435 |    1844140 | 4/17/2017 |  0.25 |  0.25 |
| 330849 |    1844140 | 4/19/2017 |  0.25 |   0.5 |
| 331108 |    1844140 | 4/20/2017 |  0.25 |  0.75 |
| 331641 |    1844140 | 4/24/2017 |  0.25 |     1 |
| 331736 |    1844140 | 4/25/2017 |  0.25 |  1.25 |
| 333761 |    1844140 | 5/5/2017  |  0.25 |   1.5 |
| 336080 |    1844140 | 5/17/2017 |     1 |   2.5 |
| 349752 |    1844140 | 8/2/2017  |  0.25 |  2.75 |
| 350994 |    1844140 | 8/9/2017  |     1 |  3.75 |
| 351426 |    1844140 | 8/11/2017 |  0.25 |     4 |
| 352132 |    1844140 | 8/15/2017 |   0.5 |   4.5 |
| 354236 |    1844140 | 8/25/2017 |  0.25 |  4.75 |
| 355580 |    1844140 | 8/29/2017 |  0.25 |     5 |
| 355650 |    1844140 | 9/5/2017  |  0.25 |  5.25 |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

How can I add the 1 year rolling time frame into the Over statement in MS SQL?

Comment: This problem was discussed in great detail on dba.se: [Date range rolling sum using window functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114403/57105)

Comment: I think your original correlated subquery should work, if you add in the same clauses to the subquery as your main query (absence = 'Unscheduled' etc).

Comment: Thanks @JamesCasey, I just overlooked that. Thanks for the help it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James mentioned, your original subquery should work. I tested it on my environment and it return correct result.

```
WITH tu AS ( 
   SELECT *
   FROM   [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] d
   WHERE lngEMPID =  1844140 AND absence = 'Unscheduled' AND lngRID IN (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
)
SELECT lngTIMEID as Id,
        lngEMPID as EmployeeId,
        dtmdateapp AS [Date], 
        stroccur AS [Value],
        (SELECT Sum(stroccur) 
         FROM   tu a 
         WHERE  a.dtmdateapp between DateAdd(d, -366, d.dtmdateapp) 
                AND d.dtmDATEAPP
                AND a.lngempid = d.lngempid) AS Total
FROM   tu d
```

Comment: The OP asked how to use the `OVER` clause, not whether the original works. The reason is obvious - the query is a *lot* cleaner. Depending on the options used, it can be a lot faster as well